# Wet bulb temperature in psychrometry

Tags: thermodynamics, hvac

"In a sling psychrometer(with dry and wet bulbs), if the moist air is not saturated(with water vapour) then it evaporates some water on the wet bulb and in turn cools the wet bulb.So the wet bulb temperature falls below the dry bulb temperature" .This is the explanation given in the book Iam using(Fundamentals of thermodynamics by Moran and Shapiro).
        1)Does this mean, the wet bulb and dry bulb temperatures are initialy same(before exposing to air)?
          2)If evaporation occurs continuously as air is blown over the bulbs, why isnt the temperature reducing continuously(it stops at a point)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1) yes,

2) evaporation continues which reduces the wet bulb temperature until the temperature stays constant because the rate of evaporative heat loss is balanced by the heat absorbed due to the temperature difference between the wet bulb temperature and ambient temperature is in equilibrium. The humdity can then be obtained from a Mollier or psychrometric chart.

Comment: No Mike, Wet bulb and dew point are [entirely different entities](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/dry-wet-bulb-dew-point-air-d_682.html).  Wet bulb is not a property of humid air directly. It is an active adiabatic process that can be calibrated to yield humidity in conjunction with the dry bulb temp. It isn't the same as dew point temperature.

Comment: @Solar Mike The book you suggested fluid mechanics by Bernard Massey was really good.Could you please suggest a good book for fluid machines(pumps,compressors,turbines,etc. explained elaborately).I know google search can give a lot of answers and this website doesnot support resource hunting but If you know a similar book(like massey), please suggest.